# Scrollspy only applying to dropdown menu

Tags: hover, dropdown, scrollspy

ever since I entered the code for a dropdown menu, scrollspy only hovers over the work items in the drop-down. It does not apply to the other a elements. I'm pretty sure I have the right data target. Thoughts? (I've tried referencing the code on the bootstrap documentation, w3, and another person's site. I must be missing something.)

```html
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse, navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynavbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="home navbar-brand">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </div><!-- end home -->
            </div><!-- end navbar-header -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#about-section">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                  "Work"
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                  </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#work-section">Work 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#work-section">Work 2</a></li>
                </ul>
                  </li>
                <li><a href="#faq-section">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact-section">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- nav -->
          </div><!-- / nav container -->
        </nav><!-- / navbar -->
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late for the original poster - but in case anybody else comes across this, the problem was probably because the target divs (or etc elements) of the dropdown links were hidden. According to Bootstrap's official documentation for ScrollSpy:

"Non-:visible target elements ignored
Target elements that are not :visible according to jQuery will be ignored and their corresponding nav items will never be highlighted."
(http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

This means if your dropdown link targets are invisible (i.e. hidden), the SpyScroll plugin won't work on them.

A workaround would be to add some hidden menus to the dropdown with the href id of some other empty elements just above and below your desired section. It may not be clear to understand my point, if anyone needs further clarification, please let me know and I'll be happy to elaborate :-)